# How to know the exact AMM implementation for a liquidity pool?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, uniswapv2

Is every liquidity pool which uses Uniswap V2 using the exact same AMM implementation? i.e. for 2 different liquidity pools, if I know the amount of liquidity (ratio of tokenA and tokenB) in the pool then I don't actually need to make any queries for a quote for a given input amount as I know the price I'll receive just from the liquidity ratios.

And whenever the liquidity ratio changes, I'll receive notice of this through events (LP leaves, LP arrives and the ratio changes, the contract will notify me by pushing, I don't need to poll this periodically, right?)

The assumption above may be wrong if i) within V2 there are different AMM implementations or ii) it's not easy to query for the current amount of tokenA and tokenB liquidity present in the pool.

Is anyone able to clarify?

Comment: Please keep to one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes: Uniswap *is* an AMM which implicates it's model across liquidity pools to provide instant (or, relatively quick) swaps.

> And whenever the liquidity ratio changes, I'll receive notice of this
> through events (LP leaves, LP arrives and the ratio changes, the
> contract will notify me by pushing, I don't need to poll this
> periodically, right?)

...in regards to this, no one is saying you *need* to poll this at all, and the quotes you'll get from US are timeously produced (i.e. at the time of swap request). You *could* poll it if you wanted to, but it's down to personal preference and fluctuating market conditions should be considered anyway whenever interacting with an AMM like Uniswap.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused. I know there is the option to poll at regular or irregular intervals. But can I somehow "subscribe" to events (push based as opposed to pull based if you like) to learn of ANY change to the state of the liquidity pool? E.g. a provider joins/leaves or the price changes? Or is polling my only option?